# Applescript cannot recognize valid command from SDEF file

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, osx-yosemite

I created valid SDEF file, that contains among other stuff a command:

```
<command name="abc" code="abc01234" description="do abc">
<cocoa class="ABCCommand"/>
    <direct-parameter description="a text parameter passed to the command">
            <type type="text" list="yes" optional="yes"/>
        </direct-parameter>
        <parameter name="abc1" code="abc1" type="text" optional="yes"
            description="abc1">
            <cocoa key="abcKey1"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="abc2" code="abc2" type="text" optional="yes"
            description="abc2">
            <cocoa key="abcKey2"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="abctrue" code="abct" type="boolean" optional="yes"
            description="xxxxxx">
            <cocoa key="abctrue"/>
        </parameter>
        <result type="list of text" description="returns ABC"/>
    </command>
```

Then I set the 'scriptable' flag to YES and compiled the program exactly as all guides recommend.
Now I created Applescript:

```
tell application "xxx123"
activate
delay 3

abc
delay 3

abc {}
delay 3

abc {"abc", "123"} without abctrue
quit
```

end tell

The problem is that Applescript being run from AS editor does not recognize 'abc' as command and complains on syntax error. Also in line 'abc {"abc", "123"} without abctrue' it says that 'abctrue:false' cannot follow the '}'. Any changes made in SDEF do not affect the syntax issues. So the question is: how to ensure that Applescript addresses up-to-date SDEF?

Comment: Cocoa Scripting is very hard to debug. I may quote Matt Neuburg : *Multiple workplaces: You have to coordinate the sdef dictionary with your code. If you make a mistake in either of them, or if you cause one of them not to match the other, some aspect of scriptability can fail mysteriously*. Re-read the Cocoa Scripting documentation about enabling scriptability and the section about Object-first Versus Verb-first Script Commands, maybe start with a simple read-only property. Enable scripting debugging in Terminal.app with `defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSScriptingDebugLogLevel 1`

Comment: But how can I coordinate?

Comment: I recommend to download the Sketch application, the Apple Cocoa Scripting sample application. Compare all components and settings with yours.

Comment: The same answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558851/how-to-force-the-script-editor-to-work-with-specific-dictionary is good for this case too.